# Calcular média SQL com campo hora

Tags: sql, datetime

Bom dia Pessoal,
Estou tendo problema para resolver o select abaixo.
Tenho o select abaixo que me retorna a quantidade de horas de um determinado evento e pelo visto retorno em varchar. O que estou tendo dificuldade é pegar esta quantidade de horas e dividir pelo outro campo Total de Registro. Já tentei fazer as conversões porém sem sucesso.

Segue print[image]

Comment: Evite colocar imagens com o código. Pode pf inclui-lo em texto? É mais fácil de validar a questão.

Comment: Qual é o banco de dados ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumindo que você tenha algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_evento
(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  dt_inicial DATETIME,
  dt_final DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO tb_evento (id, dt_inicial, dt_final) VALUES (1, '2016-05-01 23:00', '2016-05-02 03:00');
INSERT INTO tb_evento (id, dt_inicial, dt_final) VALUES (2, '2016-11-01 21:15', '2016-11-01 23:30');
INSERT INTO tb_evento (id, dt_inicial, dt_final) VALUES (3, '2016-12-24 00:00', '2016-12-25 12:00');
INSERT INTO tb_evento (id, dt_inicial, dt_final) VALUES (4, '2016-02-01 23:00', '2016-02-02 23:00');
INSERT INTO tb_evento (id, dt_inicial, dt_final) VALUES (5, '2016-03-15 08:30', '2016-03-15 16:45');
INSERT INTO tb_evento (id, dt_inicial, dt_final) VALUES (6, '2016-08-01 20:00', '2016-08-02 01:30');
```

Você pode usar a função `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` para calcular o intervalo em minutos entre duas datas, veja só.

```
SELECT
  id,
  dt_inicial,
  dt_final,
  (TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE, dt_inicial, dt_final ) / 60) AS duracao
FROM
  tb_evento;
```

Saída:

```
| id |           dt_inicial |             dt_final | duracao |
|----|----------------------|----------------------|---------|
|  1 | 2016-05-01T23:00:00Z | 2016-05-02T03:00:00Z |       4 |
|  2 | 2016-11-01T21:15:00Z | 2016-11-01T23:30:00Z |    2.25 |
|  3 | 2016-12-24T00:00:00Z | 2016-12-25T12:00:00Z |      36 |
|  4 | 2016-02-01T23:00:00Z | 2016-02-02T23:00:00Z |      24 |
|  5 | 2016-03-15T08:30:00Z | 2016-03-15T16:45:00Z |    8.25 |
|  6 | 2016-08-01T20:00:00Z | 2016-08-02T01:30:00Z |     5.5 |
```

Para calcular quantas horas um evento dura em média, você pode usar a função de agregação `AVG()`, veja só:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(1) AS qtd_eventos,
  AVG( TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE, dt_inicial, dt_final ) / 60 ) AS duracao_media
FROM
  tb_evento;
```

Saída:

```
| qtd_eventos | duracao_media |
|-------------|---------------|
|           6 |   13.33333333 |
```

Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7124ae5/8)